# Is it possible to re-attach a drive to an open DM-crypt device?

Tags: luks, dm-crypt, device-mapper

Imagine a setup where ZFS is on top of LUKS which sits on a physical drive.

While the FS is mounted, the drive drops out/is disconnected (user error, intermittent issue etc.).

Now we have the following situation:

- The drive re-appears as a "different" drive/file.
- The LUKS container can't read or write anymore because the original drive is missing.
- The ZFS can't be unmounted because the LUKS device isn't responding to IO.
- The LUKS container can't be closed because the ZFS is still using it.

Is it possible to re-attach the underlying drive to the open LUKS container? Opening it again under the same name doesn't work.

Comment: Even if you could (with `dmsetup reload` it may be possible, it lets you do unsafe stuff), corruption already happened at this point, so it probably wouldn't do any good, instead it could make things worse (additional writes which effectively cause even more corruption).

Comment: I use ZFS and btrfs which use transactional writes; a corruption from this kind of thing is highly unlikely.

Comment: You can try it, the use case is different (this adds allow_discards flag on the fly, you want to change the backing device instead) but maybe it can work, at your own risk -- https://gitlab.com/cryptsetup/cryptsetup/-/issues/196

Comment: That's a great idea! I tried reloading the table with one that has the correct major and minor dev number for the "new" device but unfortunately, it silently does nothing and keeps the old numbers.

Comment: Even after another suspend resume cycle? Then I don't know either, sorry. It's a rather dangerous thing to do. For a proper solution you'd need an independent device mapper target that suspends writes on error, patiently waits for missing device to magically reappear, and seamlessly resume. I do not know if such a thing exists. And even then it would depend on higher layers not using timeouts while writes hang in limbo...

Comment: You can't resume the device; it fails because the underlying device is not present.